# Irreducible representations of finite abelian groups over an arbitrary field

Tags: ring-theory, finite-groups, modules, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite abelian group and let $F$ be a field. If $F$ is algebraically closed, or if it is a finite field, then every irreducible $F$-representation of $A$ has cyclic image. Is this true without any assumption on $F$?

Comment: What are the arguments for the known cases, and what are your thoughts and attempts? Please edit your post rather than answering in comments. [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every irreducible representation of $A$ over a perfect (this hypothesis may be dropped) non-algebraically closed field $F$ is constructed by the following:

1. Choose a character $\chi\colon A\to\overline{F}^\times$, where $\overline F$ is an algebraic closure
2. For $\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(\overline F/F)$, the twist $\chi^\sigma:=\sigma\circ\chi$ is also a character of $A$. Let $H:=\{\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(\overline F/F):\chi^\sigma=\chi\}$.
3. Now, $\bigoplus_{\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(\overline F/F)/H}\chi^\sigma$ is an irreducible representation of $A$.

Now, the image of the above representation is isomorphic to
$$A/\bigcap_{\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(\overline F/F)/H}\ker(\chi^\sigma)=A/\ker(\chi)=\mathrm{im}(\chi).$$
Now $\mathrm{im}(\chi)\subset\overline F^\times$ is a finite abelian subgroup, which by a well-known theorem must be cyclic.

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.